# iOS 5.1 - GDB command or utility to list functions in a particular shared library

Tags: ios, gdb, nm

There are commands to list all functions in the program in gdb, but I did not find any untilities or gdb command/syntax to just list symbols in a particular shared library. nm doe s not work on arm7 shared lib. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

nm works fine on shared libraries... as long as they aren't stripped. If the library you're attempting to look at is stripped, neither nm nor gdb will show function names. If you're just interested in the Objective-C bits, [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z) is a good option. (you can get the same information from otool but it's less pretty)